How to manually delete or uninstall a ClickOnce installed app
I installed a .Net 8.0 VB app published via ClickOnce deployment on my computer. When a new version was released for some reason the app would not update. Rather than trying to use 'Add/Remove programs' (and I admit this was a crucial mistake) I just started deleted the files to manually remove all traces of the program. Unfortunately when I now try to install the new version I get the error: 'The referenced assembly is not installed on your system'.
Here's a list of all the places I deleted the published app or references to the published app. Note that * does mean every file - it means either the explicit filename or the obfuscated filename.

All files/folder in C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\* but just those referring to the published app.
All references in Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ Deployment\SideBySide\2.0\Components\*
The reference in: Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LocalSettings\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\Shell\MuiCache\*
All references in HKEY_USERS{UserIDs}\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
(I went through all the UserIDs to ensure it was not installed for any other user although I am the only person using this computer.)
Ran Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup
I did eventually run Add/Remove Uninstall but of-course this late in the game the uninstall no longer does anything.
Deleted: C:\Users{UserID}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ColibriGroup*

What did I miss? Somewhere the system still has a reference to this app. Or maybe I am misinterpreting the meaning of 'The referenced assembly is not installed on your system'?

Have you checked C:\ProgramData C:\ProgramFiles (64)

I did and found nothing in there.

If you have that old package try to reinstall it again to allow you removing it, what about 3rd parties Uninstaller tools, last suggestion is System Restore

When I said installing the new version I meant the old version with a new version number. But I also tried installing the old version, with the original version number, and both result in the error: 'The referenced assembly is not installed on your system'. I believe most of those 3rd party tools still expect the uninstaller to exist on the system and mine does not.

I followed the steps in the question to delete the references involved and installed the new version. But the problem did not occur.

Thanks Minxin, that's informative. So what I did should have worked. Maybe this issue goes all the way back to why it would not install the updated version in the first place.

Finally fixed it such that installer would re-install the program without that error. I deleted these two registry entries not in my original list:
HKEY_USERS\{obfuscasted User ID}\Software\Classes\Software
  \Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\SideBySide\2.0
  \Marks\{obfuscated program name}

and
HKEY_USERS\{obfuscasted User ID}\Software\Classes\Software
  \Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\SideBySide\2.0
  \PackageMetadata\{obfuscated program name}

It would not re-install after just deleting the first registry entry but did re-install after deleting the second registry entry so I can't say if the first registry deletion is necessary.
